# Conditional options in .vimrc for Scheme

Tags: scheme, vim

I want to toggle color-matching parens in vim when I am editing a scheme/lisp file. How can I conditionally run something in my .vimrc?

Something like:

```
if syntax == scheme:
  RainbowParenthesesToggle
```

EDIT: Currently I activate it manually

```
:RainbowParenthesesToggle
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an `autocmd` based on the `scheme` filetype:

```
autocmd FileType scheme RainbowParenthesesToggle
```

Or based [on the plugin documentation](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3772), `RainbowParenthesesLoadRound` to initialize it for `()` specifically:

```
autocmd FileType scheme RainbowParenthesesLoadRound
```

Comment: @Eduan Your edit is unnecessary, since the leading `:` is implied when defining autocommands.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use auto commands you can follow @MichaelBerkowski's advice. However if you prefer you can also do the following:

```
if (&ft == 'scheme')
    :RainbowParenthesesToggle       " Toggle it on/off
    :RainbowParenthesesLoadRound    " (), the default when toggling
    :RainbowParenthesesLoadSquare   " []
    :RainbowParenthesesLoadBraces   " {}
    :RainbowParenthesesLoadChevrons " <>
endif
```

`&ft` stands for filetype, so you can access this variable to know the current buffer's filetype. Check `:h ft` for more info.

Of course you can also have various auto commands inside this if statement, if you want to refine it a little more, or more if statements, whatever you want.

Remember the parenthesis are optional, I just like to use them. :)